# ClickListener in PagerAdapter fires on wrong position

Tags: android

I'm using [this project (Android-Coverflow)](https://github.com/crosswall/Android-Coverflow) in my app, which works as expected with one exception: when setting a `View.OnClickListener` on the single items in `instantiateItem` I do get wrong positions, i.e.:

- the middle item returns the correct position.
- the item on the right of the middle item displays the correct position (middle-item + 1)
- the item to the left of the middle item displays the wrong position: the same as the item to the right.

So if I'm scrolling so far that item with index 3 is in the middle, I get

- 3 for the middle item (correct)
- 4 for the item to the right (correct)
- 4 for the item to the left (wrong)

I add the `ClickListener` inside the `instantiateItem` method, so I would expect it to be correct...

What could I probably be missing here?

I uploaded the adapted project to Github: https://github.com/haemi/Android-Coverflow-Clicklistener-Issue - inside "transformer coverflow 2" the issue is visible. The according code is here: https://github.com/haemi/Android-Coverflow-Clicklistener-Issue/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/crosswall/coverflow/demo/Normal2Activity.java#L63

Comment: you currently getting fragment position  which are loaded not current fragment position ..

Comment: don't get it... what do I have to change there?

Comment: int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

Comment: you can get by this

Comment: got it @swalkner ??

Comment: no, because the current item is always the one in the middle; I need the one clicked on which may be the one to the left or right as well

Comment: you can write in mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener method

Comment: which method of that? OnPageSelected is called when scrolling, not on tapping

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122655/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-swalkner).

Comment: are you trying to get the position of fragment inside viewpager ?

Comment: can you find the page clicked from viewPager using ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener ??or is it mandate to find the page clicked inside the PagerAdapter

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final TextView view = new TextView(Normal2Activity.this);
        view.setText("Item " + position);
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 50, position * 10, position * 50));
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Normal2Activity.this, "position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, final int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeViewAt(position);
    }
```

Here is the full code.

```
public class Normal2Activity extends AppCompatActivity  {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal2);

    PagerContainer mContainer = (PagerContainer) findViewById(R.id.pager_container);

    final ViewPager pager = mContainer.getViewPager();

    PagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());

    pager.setClipChildren(false);


    boolean showRotate = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("showRotate",true);

    if(showRotate){
        new CoverFlow.Builder()
                .with(pager)
                .scale(0.3f)
                .pagerMargin(0f)
                .spaceSize(0f)
                .rotationY(25f)
                .build();
    }

}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final TextView view = new TextView(Normal2Activity.this);
        view.setText("Item " + position);
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 50, position * 10, position * 50));
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Normal2Activity.this, "position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("position:::::::::::::" + position);
            }
        });

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, final int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeViewAt(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 15;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: does that work for you? What's the difference to my code?

Comment: In your code, you have set the position value to view object. There is no need to set the position to view object. We can directly give the position value inside the listeners. It never changed(We have given as final). Also while using adapter we need to create the parent view with final keyword.

Comment: If you didn't give final then view object reference may be changed.

Comment: does it work for you with these changes? For me it doesn't.

Comment: I have changed this class Normal2Activity and logged the position it comes correctly.

Comment: it comes correctly on the left and right item? not only the middle one?

Comment: if yes, could you please make a pull request?

Comment: pull request sent

Comment: thanks for the PR; but I do get the toast only on the middle item; not on the left or right...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123168/discussion-between-pandiarajan-and-swalkner).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be useful for Op but for people having similar problem , The problem is caused when  using a `PageTransformer` .I just Removed the line

`viewPager.setPageTransformer(true,new MyViewPagerTransformation());` and all Click were working perfectly . I am not sure why `PageTransformer` is causing this issue , I will update it as soon I get more info .